# Convert Razor Code to aspx Code in View Folder in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I found this code, I want to convert this Razor code to aspx view engine, also please explain to me the purpose from this code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-register").click(function () {
    var posting = $.post("api/Register",
        $("#saveContactForm").serialize(),
        function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        },
        "json"
    ).complete(function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Um, this is JavaScript code.  It has nothing to do with ASP.NET server-side code.

Comment: I found this code in Razor view engine, so you mean I do not need to convert this code when I create aspx view engine?

Comment: "Convert" it to *what*?  You seem *very* confused here, and what you're asking doesn't make any sense.  Is this code failing in some way?  Is there some specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea about Javascript , I am working In ASP.net MVC 4, Web API, and I follow tutorial, I found this Code in Razor view page and i did not understand it ,  and I thought I need to convert it to aspx view engine. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code is jQuery code to AJAX post the current form to web API to register the user.

You can add this part of code to the end of ASP.NET views(.cshtml or .vbhtml file), then Razor view engine can code with JS code inside.

Comment: `"then Razor view engine can compile this part of code"` - You seem a bit confused on what JavaScript is.  This code has nothing to do with server-side view engines in ASP.NET.  It runs entirely in the browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is server side view engine allow JS code in the .cshtml file, ignore them, but it is legal to put the code in the view.

Comment: Thanks for helping, and again I so sorry I did not work with javascript before